# MySQL limit & in wont work together

Tags: mysql, inner-join, mysql-workbench

I have 3 tables and I am trying to get 10 most common languages and number of countries which use this language. My tables are:

```
City:           Name|Population|CountryCode
Country:        Name|Code
CoutryLanguage: Language|CountryCode
```

To get the top 10 languages I use the population in each city and join it with country language:

```
SELECT cl.language
FROM City ci INNER JOIN CountryLanguage cl ON ci.CountryCode = cl.CountryCode
GROUP BY cl.Language
order by sum(ci.population) desc limit 10
```

My next logic is to join country with language where language is in my new created table:

```
select co.Name, cl.Language
from Country co Inner join CountryLanguage cl on co.Code = cl.CountryCode
where cl.Language in (SELECT cl.language
FROM City ci INNER JOIN CountryLanguage cl ON ci.CountryCode = cl.CountryCode
GROUP BY cl.Language
order by sum(ci.population) desc limit 10)
```

This gives me a weird error, I can use it just fine without `LIMIT 10` but that just lists all countries and all languages. Is there a way to fix this?? I saw few questions about this but none of them is really clear. Would you mind explaining this error to me?? I can't upgrade my version of sql. Thanks in advance

I am limiting the number of languages to 10, not the whole table

Comment: What is the "weird error" you get? And the only change is the adding of `LIMIT 10`? Also, what is the purpose of the `GROUP BY` in the subquery? If there are multiple English speaking countries, then English might appear several times...

Comment: @JacobBarnes, I don't think that's the issue here. OP is limiting the possible languages for the `IN` condition, not the total result.

Comment: The limit needs to be outside the `)`.

Comment: Why are you using a subquery, why not just join the `Country` table to `CountryLanguage` table?

Comment: @JacobBarnes Hey I tried the one you linked but it didn't worked, i am limiting the subquery to only 10 languages, if i do it outside it breaks

Comment: Breaks in what way? Please include your errors.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use a LIMIT in a sub query used inside a IN filter, go with the joins approach in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one please, sorry for all the back and forward but I dont have mysql installed, just writing the SQL here....

```
select co.Name, cl.Language
from Country co 
Inner join CountryLanguage cl on co.Code = cl.CountryCode
inner join (
  SELECT language from (
    SELECT DISTINCT cl.language
    FROM City ci INNER JOIN CountryLanguage cl ON ci.CountryCode = cl.CountryCode
    GROUP BY cl.Language
    order by sum(ci.population) desc 
  ) as lng_tbl
  limit 10
) aux_tbl
on aux_tbl.Language = cl.Language
```

---

Look at a sub query as it is a table created in runtime/memory, in such case you get the following table:

```
SELECT language from (
    SELECT DISTINCT cl.language
    FROM City ci 
    INNER JOIN CountryLanguage cl 
    ON ci.CountryCode = cl.CountryCode
    GROUP BY cl.Language
    order by sum(ci.population) desc 
  ) as lng_tbl
  limit 10

>>> | language |
>>> | English |
>>> | Portuguese |
>>> | ... |
```

After this just wrap it in () and give it a name `aux_tbl`, then you can use it in the join and a normal table. As an exercise, try to get rid of the outer 
select language from () as lng_tbl.

Comment: Hello, this gives me the same error: LIMIT & IN not supported in this version

Comment: Oh I see, you need a Join instead of where clause. Give me a sec

Comment: If this join works perhaps you can remove one of the subqueries the outer one and move the limit to the other one

Comment: I mean I hoped it won't work because that's way too complicated. Mind explaining it a bit please?

Comment: see if the explanation helps you, also you had forgotten the DISTINCT which for you case is recommended

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the sub-query with a temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_lang (key(Language)) SELECT cl.language
FROM City ci INNER JOIN CountryLanguage cl ON 
ci.CountryCode = cl.CountryCode
GROUP BY cl.Language
order by sum(ci.population) desc limit 10;
select co.Name, cl.Language
from Country co Inner join CountryLanguage cl on co.Code = cl.CountryCode 
join 
tmp_lang tl on c1.Language = tl.Language;
```

Comment: You should avoid creating temp table unless this is in a batch, temp table take time to create (the server needs to "guess" the schema and run the DML)

Comment: This is because you did it already. Drop it first if it already exists with DROP TABLE IF EXISTS. The overhead of creating a temporary table is in usually the order of magnitude of 1-10 ms depending on the storage engine and the server hardware. Sub-query, even if properly optimized, also has its own comparable internal overhead. When a sub-query optimization goes wrong, the overhead of creating a temporary table is negligible compared to the bad sub-query fallout.